Leer fichero en server con Kotlin
Hola a todos y gracias por anticipado.
Estoy empezando a programar en Kotlin,imagino que para ustedes será facil.
Estoy intentando leer un fichero alojado en un servidor externo,con Kotlin.
El fichero alcanza a leerlo, y me muestra en Log.d lo leido correctamente.
Pero necesito que me devuelva el return con lo leido, y me queda en blanco.
Lo que tengo es lo siguiente
class Data(var _context: Context) {
    var al = ""
    var notes: String
        get() {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val link = "http://nombre-servidor/notes.txt"
           
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(link)
                .build()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    response.use {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
                        val body = response.body!!.string() 
                        
                        for ((name, value) in response.headers) {
                            Log.d("WWWW RESP2", body) //correcto
                            
                            al = response.body!!.string()
                            Log.d("WWWW RESP1",al) //vacio
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            Log.d("WWWW ",al) //vacio
            return al
        }
} 


Estás usando la interfaz no bloqueante de OkhttpClient, por lo que tienes una respuesta asíncrona, pero a la vez quieres que el getter de notes sea síncrono (bloqueante). En lugar de usar enqueue, deberías usar el método execute:
val response= client.newCall(request).execute() //espera hasta obtener una respuesta
response.use {...}


Gracias por la respuesta tan deprisa ,pero no me sirve, se cierra la aplicacion :-(
